# Is static const array preprocessed?

Tags: arrays, performance, static, constants

I have a lot of constants and they can be separated by groups, so I used some static const arrays of doubles.

But I need to do some calculations with this array. Therefore, I created another array that stores the calculated values - because I use them a lot.

However, I make a lot of index of the arrays, so it gets very slow too and my code, by now, is O(6^n²) - with n between 1 and 12.

My question is: what is faster, make the same calculations a lot of time, or index this array that stores those calculated?

I thought to make a lot of defines (because I know it's preprocessed), but I can't index defines what would make the code extremely big and unclear.

**short code (example)**

```
const static double array1[12] = {2,4,6,8,...};
const static double array2[12] = {1,2,3,4,...};
...
// in some function
{
...
    double stored1[12];
    for(int i = start1; i < end1; i++)
        stored1[i] = array1[i] + i*array1[i-1];
    for(int i = start2; i < end2; i++)
        stored1[i] = array2[i] + i*array2[i-1];

    // then, I'll have to index stored1 a lot of times - or create 12 auxiliary variables
    // when I need to use those arrays of stored values
    // I use these values in loops of loops of loops (they are some summations)
    // I don't use loops, but recursive functions to make this loops, but in both
    // cases, I have to index a lot of time this array (or make the same calculations)
...
}
```

Comment: `static const` array are generally well optimized by compilers (although no "preprocessing" is mandated by most language specifications like C or C++). If your array contains values computed at runtime, compilers may have some difficulties to optimize the code. That being said, this is hard to give a general answer. Can you provide an example of short code or a pseudocode to clarify the question?

Comment: If the input array is const at compile-time, and the results are going to be fixed, then why not compute them at compile-time as well?

Comment: If you say to make the calculations and put in other static const arrays, I didn't think that and it's a possibility. But it's unpractical - in case of need to change the arrays' values, for example.

Comment: I said that it could be possible to compile before, but after evolving the program, I realized that I can't calculate them before as you said. That because the array of stored values don't have a fixed rule, how you can see in the shortcode (I just edited).